# Existence and uniqueness of minimizer for Tikhonov functional

Tags: optimization, operator-theory

let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator between two Hilbert spaces. Regarding the minimization of the Tikhonov functional
$\begin{align*}
\min_{x\in X} \lVert F(x)-y \rVert_Y + \alpha \lVert x \rVert_X,
\end{align*}$

which is equivalent to solving the regularized normal equations
$\begin{align*}
 (T^*Tx - aI)x_{\alpha} = T^*y.
\end{align*}$

Under what conditions does a solution exist? Is it unique?